# Is $1/x^\alpha$ Lebesgue integrable on $(0,\infty)$ for $\alpha>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $I_\alpha=\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{1}{x^\alpha} \ d\mu(x)$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Prove that $I_\alpha\in (0,\infty)$ for $\alpha>1$.

I considered using DCT to tackle this problem, but I got stuck on choosing function $g(x)$ such that $|\frac{1}{x^\alpha}| \leq g(x)$ and $g(x)$ is integrable. In any case, I suspect that DCT is useless for this problem. Can you provide hints on how to prove this?

Comment: DCT would be off topic but anyway the statement is false. $I_\alpha=+\infty$ for all $\alpha\in\Bbb R.$ The integral always diverges at $+\infty$ or at $0$ (even at both when $\alpha=1$).

Comment: MCT might be better. Consider the sequence $f_n = 1/x^\alpha \times \mathbb 1_{[1/n,n]}(x)$

Comment: @AnneBauval oh I could see my fault, thank you very much . I forgot that DCT requires a sequence $f_n$ which converges to $f$. Maybe i will ask my teacher to modify the problem.

Comment: @KennyWong So do we use MCT to explain that it is not Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: @Linda Yes, you can use MCT to prove that the integral of $1/x^\alpha$ is infinity

Comment: @KennyWong Thanks a million!